# Why is another function being called on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a dialog box, with every key in object parameter as an input.

[** **Fiddle** **](http://jsfiddle.net/8JChZ/4/)

```
function dialog(opt){
    for (var key in opt) {
        if (key=="msg"  && typeof opt[key]==="string")
            alert.append(opt[key]); //alert message
        else if (typeof opt[key]==="function") { //alert functional button
            console.log(key, "is a function");
            $("<input type=button>").val(key).appendTo(alert)
                .on("click",function(){ console.log(key, 'called'); opt[key](); close(); });
        } else { //alert pretty button
            console.log(key, "is not a function");
            //$("<input type=button>").val(key).appendTo(alert).click(close);
        }
    }
}
dialog({msg:"Yes or no?",yes:function(){},no:''});
```

Only 'yes' input is being created but when I click on it, 'no' is called as a function:

```
yes is function         dialog.js:41
no is not a function    dialog.js:44
no called               dialog.js:43
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'no' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Comment: Not that I think it will make a difference but you could cut out some overhead of jQuery by using the native `typeof` comparison operator. For example: `if(typeof opt[key] === "function")`. It's probably what jQuery does internally anyway.

Comment: ok I will do thank you, I have been thinking on changing to javascript but I'm very used to jQuery.

Comment: I think this is a closure problem...

Comment: @Quentin It is a duplicate, but it's a hard one to search for until you know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're sharing the `key` variable between all your handlers, and their value is its value after it exits the loop, `'no'`. The solution is to bind each handler, jquery lets you assign data to each event by passing an extra data argument to `$.on`

```
function dialog(opt){
    for (var key in opt) {
        $("<input type=button value="+key+" style='margin:5% 3%;padding:3% 7%;'>").
        appendTo('#alert').
        on("click", {fn: opt[key]}, function(e){
            // Whatever you bound to the argument is stored in e.data
            if (typeof e.data.fn ==="function") {
                e.data.fn();
            } else {
                alert('You passed in "' +  e.data.fn + '"');
            }
        });
    }
}
dialog({
    msg:'Whatever',
    yes:function(){ 
        alert('clicked yes')
    },
    no:''
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/8JChZ/3/

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea how to solve this.